# how to create public app in shopify and provide app url and whitelisted url in php

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I have created public app and set app url which is in laravel where I am getting timestamp,shop and hmac. In whitelisted url I am putting url like `https://www.example.net/get-access-token` which is also in laravel.

How to connect client (which will install the app) to my public app?

How the payment process is handling when we click on get app?